# How exactly do I output the distance between two touch points in Xcode for iOS?

Tags: xcode, ios, touch

Here is my goal: to have a user touch two different points on the screen, and the app will output a number that represents the distance between these points. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11):

At a simple level, you could simply use a pythagorean theorem approach as follows to calculate the distance between the two points.

```
double distance = sqrt(pow((x2 - x1), 2.0) + pow((y2 - y1), 2.0));
```

I presume you're using a `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method (after registering as a UIResponder and receiving multiple touches via `[self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];`), in which case you can extract the `CGPoint`'s `.x` and `.y` values by extracting the provided [UITouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html)es from the NSSet and using the `locationInView` method to obtain the `CGPoint` for the touch in question.

If you've not used these classes before, I'd be tempted to read up on:

- [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [UITouch Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITouch)

However, if you've not yet used such things before, I'd also recommend a read of the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541) documentation to give you a good grounding. (You might also want to take a step back and consume the [Creating an iPhone Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007595) docs, as these go into quite a bit of detail (along with source code) as to how you can capture touch events, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new at this; Ive only created soundboards before. This is my first real application. Do you know where I can find a tutorial for this?

Comment: @Mike I've updated my answer with some additional references which should hopefully help. (You might also want to take a step back and consume the [Creating an iPhone Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007595) docs, as this goes into quite a bit of detail (along with source code) as to how you can capture touch events, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

When you receive a touch event, you get its xy coordinates. You can use that formula we all learned in grade school, `d = sqrt((x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2))`. This will get you the distance in pixels between them. The iphone4 has 326 ppi so divide the distance you get by 326 and you get an estimate of the distance between touches in inches.